# Was the track "Estasi Dell Anima" newly composed for "Zombieland"?

Tags: soundtrack, zombieland

From the [Zombieland](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1156398/) (2009) score, there is a track "Estasi Dell Anima", from when Tallahassee locks himself in the booth at Pacific Playland to distract all the zombies.

Does anyone know, is this piece based on a classical piece, or some other piece? 
It is a musically gorgeous track, but it is all of 1m54s long. 
I'd love to get a longer or extended version of this song.

Or was it a new piece composed for the movie, and no longer rendition exists?

Comment: Be careful as this question takes a small left into asking *"where can I find this music?"*  Otherwise, there is a good question in here.

Comment: No, I have the basic track from the score, so I'm not asking where I can get that official music. Just wondering if there's something bigger. :) Already hit up Amazon for the score. ;)

Comment: What makes you think it is based on another piece of music?

Comment: It's not that I think it is based on another piece, but that I'm wondering if it is. Really, I'm just wondering if there isn't a longer rendition of it somewhere, because it is a beautiful piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estasi dell Anima was composed for the movie by David Sardy, there isn't a longer version. Searching through Spotify, I found Ennio Morricone's L'Estasi Dell'oro, which has a similar feel and might be an inspiration. It has similar instrumentation (discounting the electric guitar) and a driving beat with flourishes leading to a grand orchestral swell. It's 3:23 minutes long, might be helpful.